# mcrypt_decrypt(): Size of key is too large for

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to Decrypt a data with a key of AES 256 61 character length.
Please refer below code:
$key is AES 256 61 character length.

mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, str_rand(61));

Error:
mcrypt_decrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm

Please advice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all. AES256 requires a 256-bit (that is, 8 character) key; the key you are passing to it is too large.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually I'm getting the key from a third party and that is what they have given. Sorry I'm not really familiar on decryption. Should I ask them to change the key then? like make it to 8 character? or what is your suggestion then?

Comment: Either the key they've given you isn't actually an AES256 key, or it's in a different format than you think it is, or it's supposed to be preprocessed in some way. In any case, contact them for details.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth: The IV (last argument, `str_rand(61)` here) is an essential part of the decryption process. Choosing one randomly for decryption **will not work**; its value is typically included with the encrypted message.